# Error in driver.Create() while creating a new raster

Tags: python, gdal, hyperspectral-sensor

I want to divide each band of the hyperspectral data by a factor and then save it into a new raster. The function driver.Create() is showing an error and outDS raster is giving Nonetype value.
outRefR is the numpy array of result after applying the factor.

Here is the code block,

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

img_more_bands = gdal.Open("/content/drive/file1")
data = img_more_bands.ReadAsArray()

ang=gdal.Open(r"/content/drive/MyDrive/file2")
angle=ang.ReadAsArray()

outRefR=data/np.cos(angle)


driver=gdal.GetDriverByName('ENVI')


outFN = '/content/drive/MyDrive/output.tif'  # Specify a file name with the appropriate extension

outDS = driver.Create(outFN, outRefR.shape[2], outRefR.shape[1], outRefR.shape[0], gdal.GDT_Float32)

for i in range(outRefR.shape[0]):
    bnd = outDS.GetRasterBand(i + 1)
    bnd.WriteArray(outRefR[i, :, :])

outDS = None
```

And here is the error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-aa7e987b6715> in <cell line: 5>()
      4 
      5 for i in range(outRefR.shape[0]):
----> 6     bnd = outDS.GetRasterBand(i + 1)
      7     bnd.WriteArray(outRefR[i, :, :])
      8 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'
```

Comment: I suppose that `outDS = driver.Create(outFN, outRefR.shape[2], outRefR.shape[1], outRefR.shape[0], gdal.GDT_Float32)` has failed and therefore outDS is of type NoneType. In this answer the number of bands is also defined https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/348515/30184.

Comment: @user30184 I have given the number of bands from the shape of the original dataset as outRefR.shape[0]

Comment: @SonofaBeach I have included the complete code here. I have defined the driver in the code